# Android: search three columns in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Im coding an application that logs the cell tower ids of all the connected cells and writes the values to a database

ID     COLUMN_OP_ID     LAC      CID

x        xxxxx       xxxxx      xxxxxxx

My code:

```
  public String findProduct(String lacId) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_TOWERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LAC + " =  \"" + lacId + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        String lac = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            lac =cursor.getString(2);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            lac = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return lac;
    }
```

However with this code i get all the rows containing this no. I want to implement a function to search all the three columns of Op_Id, lac and cid, to narrow my search and narrow my search down further. However I am not able to search across all three column to narrow my search

eg.

```
 public String findRecord(String id, String lac, String cid)
```

How do I design a function like this?
Thanks, Sahil

Comment: ....and your question is?

Comment: you can have many conditions in your where clause. CID = cid AND LAC = lac AND so in.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.

```
 public String findID(String lacId, String opId, String cid) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_TOWERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_LAC + " = \"" + lacId + "\" AND " + COLUMN_OPERATOR_ID + " = \"" + opId + "\" AND " + COLUMN_CID + " = \"" + cid + "\"";

        System.out.println(query);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        String id= null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            lac =cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            id = null;
        }
            db.close();
        return id;
    }
```